# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE with comma as decimal separator

Tags: mysql

How can I import a TSV file when the numbers use comma as a decimal separator?

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '$filename' INTO TABLE dados_meteo IGNORE 3 LINES 
($fields[0], $fields[1], $fields[2], $fields[3], $fields[4], $fields[5])
 SET POM='$pom'
 ;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to replace ',' to '.' when loading.

For example -

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE dados_meteo
(@var1, @var2)
SET column1 = REPLACE(@var1, ',', '.'), column2 = REPLACE(@var2, ',', '.')
```

Answer (score 0):

If $field[0] is your numeric:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '$filename' INTO TABLE dados_meteo IGNORE 3 LINES 
(@var1, $fields[1], $fields[2], $fields[3], $fields[4], $fields[5])
SET POM='$pom', $field[0] = CONVERT(REPLACE(@var1,',', ''), DECIMAL(10));
```

If more are numeric, simply repeat the pattern with a @var2, @var3, etc. You'll want to replace the DECIMAL(10) with whatever your field really is.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew I am trying to post the final code - is giving me a syntax error

Comment: `LOAD DATA INFILE '$filename' INTO TABLE dados_meteo IGNORE 3 LINES 
(@var1, @var2, @var3, @var4, @var5, @var6)
 SET POM='$pom',
 $field[0] = CONVERT(REPLACE(@var1,',', ''), DECIMAL(10)),
 $field[1] = CONVERT(REPLACE(@var2,',', ''), DECIMAL(10)),
 $field[2] = CONVERT(REPLACE(@var3,',', ''), DECIMAL(10)),
 $field[3] = CONVERT(REPLACE(@var4,',', ''), DECIMAL(10)),
 $field[4] = CONVERT(REPLACE(@var5,',', ''), DECIMAL(10)),
 $field[5] = CONVERT(REPLACE(@var6,',', ''), DECIMAL(10))
 ;`

Comment: are you running this via PHP? What error are you getting where exactly?

Comment: Yes via php. 
Undefined variable: field
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= CONVERT(REPLACE(@var1,',', ''), DECIMAL(10)), = CONVERT(REPLACE(@var2,',', ' at line 4

Comment: Well, there you go. I should have typed '$fields[0]' but I left off the 's'.

Comment: That's it. But the problem is that I can't get the '.' as decimal point on the database