# Insert CSV into MySQL with PHP alter values

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a little project where i do export data from a program (CSV) and i want to import this data into my own project. I am writing this in PHP with MySQL.

The issue I am having is that the exported CSV exports some values (currency) with a comma, and MySQL when using decimal(12,2) does not accept a comma to be inserted.

The data look as follows:

> Date,"Description","Account","Others","Code","Transaction","Ammount","Kind","Comment"
>   20180731,"StoreA","123456789","","BA","Af","3,99","Vendingmachine","comment"
>   20180731,"StoreB","987654321","","BA","Af","13,40","PaymentTerminal","comment"
>
> etc.

The code I am currently using to import the data is as follows:

```
<?php
    include ("DB_connect.php");

    if ($_FILES['filetoupload']['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {

        if(isset($_FILES['filetoupload'])) {
            $file = $_FILES['filetoupload'];

            //File properties
            $file_name = $file["name"];
            $file_tmp = $file["tmp_name"];
            $file_size = $file["size"];
            $file_error = $file["error"];

            //Workout the file extension
            $file_ext = explode(".", $file_name);
            $file_ext =  strtolower(end($file_ext));

            $allowed = array('csv');

            if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed)) {
                if($file_error === 0) {
                    if($file_size <= 5242880) {
                        $file_name_new = $file_name;
                        $file_destination = "../Uploads/" . $file_name_new;

                        if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)){
                            echo $file_destination;
                            $conn = db_connect();      

                            $query = mysqli_query($conn, "LOAD DATA INFILE '" . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "../Uploads/" . "/" . $file["name"] . "' INTO TABLE transactions;");

                            header('Refresh: 0;TransactieUpload.php?s=succes');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Is there any way to alter the data during the upload / import to replace the comma by a dot?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Here is a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735395/mysql-load-data-infile-with-comma-as-decimal-separator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE with comma as decimal separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735395/mysql-load-data-infile-with-comma-as-decimal-separator)

Comment: Can't realy figure it out how to get this to work... can you help me out?

Here is the import code i am using now wich works fine without the amount:

LOAD DATA INFILE "file_to_import.csv" INTO TABLE transactions
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES;